# Cucumber: Class not found com.example.runner.RunnerTest

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a `maven` project to run `cucumber` and `selenium`.  The `*.feature` files are defined in the `src/features`, and the steps are defined in the `src/test/java/com/example/steps`.

[image]

I have also defined a test runner class as below:

```
package com.example.runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
             features={"src/features"},
             glue="com/example/steps")
public class RunnerTest {

}
```

The problem is: **When i run the class it complains with:**

```
Class not found com.example.runner.RunnerTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.runner.RunnerTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The question is, **why it does not recognized the runner calss?**

---

**Update:**

when i run the feature file by

**open feature file -> right click -> Run as -> 1 cucumber feature**

*It works well*

I changed the `glue="com/example/steps"` to `glue="com.example.steps"` and it complains with :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.steps.Click_Steps.i_am_in(Click_Steps.java:23)
    at ✽.Given I am in "http://suvian.in/selenium/1.6checkbox.html"(CheckBox.feature:14)
```

and when i refer to the file:

```
base.getDriver().navigate().to(uri);
```

But as i said, this line work pretty well when i run the feature file using `Run as -> Cucumber`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider re-organizing your structure in the following way:

```
src/
├── main/
│   └── java/
|        └── ...
│   
└── test/
    ├── java/
    |    └── com.example/
    |         ├── checkbox/
    |         |    ├── CheckboxSteps/
    |         |    └── CheckboxTest/
    |         ├── click_button/
    |         |    ├── ClickButtonSteps/
    |         |    └── ClickButtonTest/
    |         └── ...
    |
    └── resources/
         └── features/
              ├── checkbox/
              |    └── checkbox.feature/
              ├── click_button/
              |    └── ClickButton.feature/
              └── ...
```

This will improve both your code organization and traceability in case of failing tests.

`CheckboxTest` should then look like this:

```
package com.example.checkbox;

   import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
   import cucumber.api.SnippetType;
   import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

   @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
   @CucumberOptions(
                snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE,
                glue = {"com.example.checkbox"},
                features = "classpath:features/checkbox")
   public class CheckboxTest {

    /*
    * This class should be empty, step definitions should be in separate classes.
    */

   }
```

Then put your step definitions in `CheckboxSteps`.

You should be able to run `CheckboxTest` now.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late. But try to do the following and this should work.

Go to Project -> Clean.

Rerun the Runner class.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by two ways:

**Solution 1:** Clean your project
**Solution 2:** right click on *Project -> Maven -> Update project ->* Check the box: *Force update snapshot or releases -> OK* and then run your suite