# Issue while running cucumber java project "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumberOptions.TestRunner"?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, junit, cucumber

Login feature File is working fine...

> ```
> Feature: Application Login
>
> Scenario: Home page default login
> Given User is on Netbanking Landing Page
> When User login into application with username and password
> Then Home page is populated
> And Cards are displayed
> ```

TestRunner class is given below:

> package cucumberOptions;
> import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
> import cucumber.api.SnippetType;
> import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
> import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
>
> ```
> @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
> @CucumberOptions(
>       snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE,
>       features = "feature",//C:\\Users\\Sanket\\Documents\\QA_testing\\Selenium\\Eclipse\\Automation\\src\\test\\java\\feature\\Login.feature",
>       glue = {"classpath:/cucumberOptions/src/test/java/stepDefinition"})
>         //C:\\Users\\Sanket\\Documents\\QA_testing\\Selenium\\Eclipse\\Automation\\src\\test\\java\\stepDefinitons\\stepDefinition.java
> ```
>
> parameter to define stepDefinition file
>
> ```
> public class TestRunner {
>       
> }
> ```

pom.xml file is given below:

> ```
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>
>   <groupId>Cucumber</groupId>
>   <artifactId>Automation</artifactId>
>   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
>
>   <name>Automation</name>
>   <url>http://www.example.com</url>
>
>   <properties>
>     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>     <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
>     <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
>   </properties>
>   
>   <dependencies>
>       <dependency>
>     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
>     <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
>     <version>1.2.2</version>
>   </dependency> 
>   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
>     <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
>     <version>1.2.2</version>
>     <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
>     <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
>     <version>1.2.2</version>
> </dependency>
>   <dependency>
>           <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
>           <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
>           <version>1.2.2</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm -->
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
>     <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0.3</version>
>     <type>pom</type>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
>     <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
>     <version>2.6</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
>     <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
>     <version>3.141.59</version>
> </dependency>
> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
>     <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
>     <version>2.12.2</version>
>     <scope>provided</scope>
> </dependency>
>       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
>           <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
>           <version>7.1.0</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>junit</groupId>
>     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>     <version>4.13</version>
>     <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
>       
>       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
>   </dependencies>
>   <build>
>     <pluginManagement>
>       <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>           <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>3.1.0</version>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>           <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>3.0.2</version>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>3.8.0</version>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>2.22.1</version>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>3.0.2</version>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>           <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>2.5.2</version>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>           <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>2.8.2</version>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>           <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>3.7.1</version>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>           <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>3.0.0</version>
>         </plugin>
>       </plugins>
>     </pluginManagement>
>   </build>
> </project>
> ```

STEPDEFINITION file showing cucumber class problem. class is given below:

> package stepDefinitons;
>
> ```
> import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
> import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
> import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
> import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
> import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
> import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
> import cucumber.annotation.en.when;
> import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;      
> @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
> @RunWith (Cucumber.class)
> public class stepDefinition {
>
>   @Given("^User is on Netbanking Landing Page$")
>     public void user_is_on_netbanking_landing_page() throws Throwable {
>     
>       System.out.println("Navigate to Login page");
>     }
>     
>     @When("^User login into application with username and password$")
>     public void user_login_into_application_with_username_and_password()
>    throws Throwable {                 
>         System.out.println("Logged in success");
>     }
>
>     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
>   @Then("^Home page is populated$")
>     public void home_page_is_populated() throws Throwable {
>        System.out.println("Validated Home page");
>     }
>
>     @And("^Cards are displayed$")
>     public void cards_are_displayed() throws Throwable {
>         System.out.println("Validated cards");
>     }
>
> }
> ```

I have tried all combination of dependencies in pom.xml file. But not getting  success in running TestRunner file. Feature class has connected to stepDefinition class. But getting ClassNotFound exception with cucumberOptions.TestRunner class. PLease can anybody help me with this issue????

Comment: This [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115622/cucumber-class-not-found-com-example-runner-runnertest) might help you

Comment: Remove ` <scope>test</scope>`